# Manipulate some poorly delimited data into a useful CSV

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have some output in the form of:

```
count  id     type
588    10 |    3
 10    12 |    3
883    14 |    3
 98    17 |    3
 17    18 |    1
77598    18 |    3
10000    21 |    3
17892     2 |    3
20000    23 |    3
 63    27 |    3
  6     3 |    3
 2446    35 |    3
 14    4 |    3
 15     4 |    1
253     4 |    2
19857     4 |    3
 1000     5 |    3
...
```

Which is pretty messy and needs to be cleaned up to a CSV so I can gift it to a Project Manager for them the spreadsheet the hell out of it.

The core of the problem is this: I need the output of this to be:

> id, sum_of_type_1, sum_of_type_2, sum_of_type_3

An example of this is id "4":

```
14    4 |    3
 15     4 |    1
253     4 |    2
19857     4 |    3
```

This should instead be:

```
4,15,253,19871
```

Unfortunately I'm pretty rubbish at this sort of thing, I've managed to get all the lines cleaned up and into CSV but I haven't been able to deduplicate and group the rows. Right now I have this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {split($line, part, " "); print part[1],part[2],part[4]}' | awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}'
```

But all that does is clean up the rubbish characters and print the rows again.

What is the best way of getting massaging the rows into the above-mentioned output?

Comment: Do you even want to sum the counts together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A way to do it is to put everything in a hash.

```
# put values into a hash based on the id and tag
awk 'NR>1{n[$2","$4]+=$1}
END{
    # merge the same ids on the one line
    for(i in n){
        id=i;
        sub(/,.*/,"",id);
        a[id]=a[id]","n[i];
    }
    # print everyhing
    for(i in a){
        print i""a[i];
    }
}'
```

*edit: my first answer didn't answer the question properly*

Comment: Yep, this did the trick very nicely. Thanks! Only thing is I didn't account for some types from IDs to be empty and thus messing up the CSV, but I can work that little detail out

Comment: @Paul Maybe add `NF<4{$4="no_type";}` at the start

Answer (score 11):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

<>;  # Skip the header.

my %sum;
my %types;
while (<>) {
    my ($count, $id, $type) = grep length, split '[\s|]+';
    $sum{$id}{$type} += $count;
    $types{$type} = 1;
}

say join ',', 'id', sort keys %types;
for my $id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %sum) {
    say join ',', $id, map $_ // q(), @{ $sum{$id} }{ sort keys %types };
}
```

It keeps two tables, table of types and table of ids. For each id, it stores the sum per type.

Answer (score 5):

If [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is an option for you, then

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1, $2, $4}' OFS=, file | datamash -t, -s --filler=0 crosstab 2,3 sum 1
,1,2,3
10,0,0,588
12,0,0,10
14,0,0,883
17,0,0,98
18,17,0,77598
2,0,0,17892
21,0,0,10000
23,0,0,20000
27,0,0,63
3,0,0,6
35,0,0,2446
4,15,253,19871
5,0,0,1000
```

Answer (score 4):

Python (and the `pandas` library in particular is very suited for this kind of work

```
data = """count  id     type
588    10 |    3
 10    12 |    3
883    14 |    3
 98    17 |    3
 17    18 |    1
77598    18 |    3
10000    21 |    3
17892     2 |    3
20000    23 |    3
 63    27 |    3
  6     3 |    3
 2446    35 |    3
 14    4 |    3
 15     4 |    1
253     4 |    2
19857     4 |    3
 1000     5 |    3"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO # to read from string, not needed to read from file

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=sep='\s+\|?\s*', index_col=None, engine='python')
```

This reads the csv data to a `pandas DataFrame`

```
    count  id  type
0     588  10     3
1      10  12     3
2     883  14     3
3      98  17     3
4      17  18     1
5   77598  18     3
6   10000  21     3
7   17892   2     3
8   20000  23     3
9      63  27     3
10      6   3     3
11   2446  35     3
12     14   4     3
13     15   4     1
14    253   4     2
15  19857   4     3
16   1000   5     3
```

Then we [group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) this data by `id`, and take the sum of column `count`

```
df_sum = df.groupby(('type', 'id'))['count'].sum().unstack('type').fillna(0)
```

The `unstack` [reshapes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking) this to move the id's to the columns, and the `fillna` fills the empty fields with 0's

```
df_sum.to_csv()
```

This returns

```
id,1,2,3
2,0.0,0.0,17892.0
3,0.0,0.0,6.0
4,15.0,253.0,19871.0
5,0.0,0.0,1000.0
10,0.0,0.0,588.0
12,0.0,0.0,10.0
14,0.0,0.0,883.0
17,0.0,0.0,98.0
18,17.0,0.0,77598.0
21,0.0,0.0,10000.0
23,0.0,0.0,20000.0
27,0.0,0.0,63.0
35,0.0,0.0,2446.0
```

Because the dataframe contains missing data (empty id-type combinations), pandas transforms the `int`s to `float` (limitation of the internal workings)
If you know the inputs wil be int only, you could change the next-to last line to `df_sum = df.groupby(('type', 'id'))['count'].sum().unstack('type').fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: You should explain what the code you've provided does, so it's helpful to everyone who sees this post, rather than this one specific person.

Comment: Is this clearer? I also corrected the regex for the seperator

Comment: Looks good to me. Thanks for adding an explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Perl to loop over the CSV file and accumulating the sum of the appropriate types in a hash while on the way. And in the end, display the information collected for every ID.

## Data Structure

```
%h = (
   ID1    =>  [ sum_of_type1, sum_of_type2, sum_of_type3 ],
   ...
)
```

This helps in making sense of the code below:

## Perl

```
perl -wMstrict -Mvars='*h' -F'\s+|\|' -lane '
   $, = chr 44, next if $. == 1;

   my($count, $id, $type) = grep /./, @F;
   $h{ $id }[ $type-1 ] += $count}{
   print $_, map { $_ || 0 } @{ $h{$_} } for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h
' yourcsvfile
```

## Output

```
2,0,0,17892
3,0,0,6
4,15,253,19871
5,0,0,1000
...
```

Answer (score 1):

my take, not too different from others. Uses GNU awk which has arrays of arrays

```
gawk '
    NR == 1 {next}
    {count[$2][$4] += $1}
    END {
        for (id in count) {
            printf "%d", id
            for (type=1; type<=3; type++) {
                # add zero to coerce possible empty string into a number 
                printf ",%d", 0 + count[id][type]
            }
            print ""        # adds the newline for this line
        }
    }
' file
```

outputs

```
2,0,0,17892
3,0,0,6
4,15,253,19871
5,0,0,1000
10,0,0,588
12,0,0,10
14,0,0,883
17,0,0,98
18,17,0,77598
21,0,0,10000
23,0,0,20000
27,0,0,63
35,0,0,2446
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to sum up values based upon your id column,

I have added one awk statement after your code

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {split($line, part, " "); print part[1],part[2],part[4]}' abcd | awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","}{arr[$2,$3]+=$1;}END{for ( i in arr ) print i,arr[i];}'
```

Go ahead with this ...